# save command lines used in Linux session

Tags: linux

I am brand new to Linux as of today.  I have learned how to access a Linux cluster from my Windows 7 desktop computer.  I connect to the cluster using software called PuTTY which opens a command window on my desktop.  Then I can type Linux commands in that window one line at a time to submit instructions to the cluster.

Before I close that command window and presumably sever my connection for the session, is there some way I can save all of the command lines I used in this session into a text file on my desktop for future reference?

If so, what command line should I use?

Can I also save all the text in the command window?  In other words, can I save the command lines I typed and the resulting text that appeared in the command window?

I imagine these are very basic questions, but these are also questions I have always had about DOS lines on my desktop as well.

Thank you for any advice.  Sorry if I must provide a more specific term than 'Linux'.  I have obtained a Linux reference and will work through some beginning-level exercises soon, but saving the commands used in my first session seems rather important and somewhat pressing.

Comment: In general, history is preserved between sessions (assuming the same system and user account), so using the up arrow will generally work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From PuTTY's **Configuration** window click on **Logging**:

   [image: 1]
2. Select **All session output**:

   [image: 2]
3. Changing the default **Log file name** (putty.log) is optional, but you should **Browse** and specify a save location for the file.
4. Modify any other options as you see fit (for example, whether the existing log file should be overwritten, appended to or you should be asked every time).
5. That's it, from now on all session output will be saved to your specified log. Click **Open** to start your session and type a few commands to test, then close the window and check the log file to confirm.

Comment: Thank you.  I wrote down all of the command lines used in my first session using the up-arrow key to scroll back through them.  There were only maybe 10 command lines.  I will use your instructions for future sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely interfacing with the Bash shell once you SSH into your Linux box.  If that is the case then Bash already keeps a backup of your commands that you have previously typed.

The filename is .bash_history and is located inside your home directory.  `cd ~ && cat .bash_history`.

If you are not using Bash on your Linux machine then most, if not all shells, have a similar file similarly named.  Typically, inside of your home directory and prefixed with a `.` so use `ls -a` if you are looking for it :)